# Converting a value to Currency

Tags: mysql

this seems like a simple fix but I'm stuck.
I have a list of values ex: 8564899 that should be displayed as 85,648.99 and NOT 8,564,899.
If I can't convert to currency. I would just like to cut the last two values off.
Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried the following solutions:

```
FORMAT(Value, 'F')
ROUND(Value, 2)
STR(Value, 7, 2)
CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2), Value)
```

Comment: Maybe divide by 100?

Comment: FORMAT would be the my choice and produces 85,649 if value is divided by 100- see https://dbfiddle.uk/zhm88mdT btw format(value,2) produces 85,648.99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT FORMAT(Value/100, 2) AS Amount
```

This should also work if Value is stored as a string/text/(var)char.

If you need specific locale formatting look at the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) for FORMAT.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT concat(substring(Value, 1, length(Value)-2), ".", substring(Value, -2, 2)) as numWithDecimal
```

Maybe like this to cut the value

Comment: Hi, This gave me the error Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Argument data type float is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string

```
CONVERT(Value,char)
```

And insert the '.' on the position in the string that you want

Comment: H, This results in 5.50899e+006

Comment: Can you write some value example to test? And what version of mySQL are you using?